# Ext.Net Framework, good or bad? Useable for productive work in community version? Alternatives?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

as I started to work with Ext.Net I recognized that there is no documentation at the moment, therefore I feel like it's really hard to develop something with that Framework.

So my question is, is Ext.Net as ASP.NET Framework useable? Good, bad, worse? 
In terms of productive work, is the community version (no premium support) useable to code in a productive way or is it to buggy, or ... ?

Any Alternatives to the Ext.Net Framework?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, let's start.
Ext.NET is very good and userful framework. Because:

1. Ext.NET is based on ExtJs. ExtJs is most powerful JavaScript framework for RIA. Of course you can look for analogs but I haven't found them.
2. Good realization of Ext.NET. The problem was in integration of very complex JavaScript framework with ASP.NET for .NET developers and this problem was solved very good.
3. Yes, Ext.NET don't have documentation, but examples on examples.ext.net and documentation of ExtJs  is enough. And in any time you can look in source code and look at some commentaries and logic.
4. I can't imagine some buisiness application in Web which realization will be impossible with Ext.NET.
5. If have you will have any question you always can ask them on forum of Ext.NET. And developers or community always will try to help you.
6. And last one that Ext.NET have very good legacy from ExtJs - a lot of plugins.